# Why is the Joule-Thomson-process irreversible?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, reversibility

It is always said that the Joule-Thomson process is irreversible, but why?
Reversible means that the process is invertible, i.e. if the external conditions are reversed, the process itself is reversed. I now imagine the process as follows:
First, a small pressure $p_1$ is applied in chamber 1 and a large pressure $p_2$ in chamber 2. After some time, the entire gas is then in chamber 1. Now I exchange the two pressures and the gas flows quasistatically into chamber 2, which is the Joule-Thomson process. If I were to reverse the external conditions again, i.e. swap $p_1$ and $p_2$, the entire gas would flow into chamber 1 again and the initial state would be restored. As I understand it, this means that the process would be reversible.

Comment: In your 'first' step, the entire gas does not go into chamber 1 - the pressure equalizes between chambers 1 and 2. Free expansion is quite different...

Comment: The pressures in the individual chambers are kept constant, so there can be no pressure equalisation except when all the gas is in one chamber.

Comment: Reversible means that the two pressures remain the same, and the gas flows backwards to the original state without anything else changing.  Also, the forward process is not quasi-static.

Answer (score 1):

> Reversible means that the process is invertible, i.e. if the external conditions are reversed, the process itself is reversed.

Reversible means that you can make arbitrarily small changes in conditions to reverse the process.

A puck on a frictionless floor can be driven in either direction by arbitrarily small amounts of force.  Moving it from A to B is reversible.

For the expansion process to be reversible, we'd need to make a small change that returned the gas to the initial chamber.  That doesn't happen.  "Exchanging the pressures" requires significant energy or entropy input.

> the gas flows quasistatically into chamber 2

A quasi static change would require the two chambers to already be in equilibrium.  As they don't have the same pressure, this is not true.  We can't let a tiny amount of gas flow through the orifice in one direction and then let a tiny amount of gas flow back.  The pressure difference prevents this.